# How to pass variables between scripts running in parallel

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I'm running IIS on a Windows Server w/PHP 5.3.  I have two scripts; let's call them initiator.php and worker.php.  A user calls initiator.php and in this script a variable is defined; let's call it $input.  I would like to take this $input variable and pass it to worker.php like so:

```
$oShell = new COM('Wscript.Shell');
$oShell->Run("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.3/php/worker.php -a $input",0,False);
```

In worker.php I have the following to pick up the $input variable passed from initiator.php.

```
$aCliOpts = getopt('a:');
$input_from_initiator = $aCliOpts['a'];
```

This works great.  initiator.php's $input variable is successfully passed to worker.php which picks it up and initiator.php keeps chugging.  However, worker.php then takes it's own $input_from_initiator variable, runs through some quick code of it's own and creates a third variable called $output_from_worker.  It is this variable that I need initiator.php to read a little ways into it's processing.  This is where I'm getting hung up.

I've tried passing the variable back to initiator.php from worker.php the same way it a variable as passed in the beginning and this did not work.  I've also tried to use:

```
header('Location: initiator.php?var=value')
```

using HTTP GET params but to no avail.

My last resort is for worker.php to write this variable's value to disk then have initiator.php read from disk.  I hate to do this due to the latent disk I/O.  Speed is very important to this script.

Is there a way two PHP processes can pass variables between each other in memory?

Comment: Why are you running a separate script in the first place? Why would you use a COM object to do this? Are you sure it's safe to interpolate `$input` into that string? How could HTTP headers ever work when no HTTP is involved?

Comment: By default, as far as i know, there is no way to do this. Multiple php scripts run as separate processes. The only way you could share some variables is by using pcntl fork, which will basicly copy your current process and run it from there on in a separate process. But beware of file descriptors and connetions to external services, as those are shared between processes and once one process closes a connection  for example, you will get errors in the others.

Comment: under nix* easy, under windows _ a db? doing some research on php *daemons* made yield an answer

Comment: you could try something with memcache (there seems to be a version available for IIS), but you still need a way to sync your processes...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `file_get_contents()` http://php.net/file_get_contents, which you can pass a URL to. So you could use the Query String like:

```
 $var = file_get_contents('http://site.tld/worker.php?input='.$input);
```

And in `worker.php`, simply echo your result.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame you're running on Windows, because the [sys5 extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) on *nix is marvelous!

You can always use files or a database etc for communication.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help although I ended up doing something a little different than my original question.  I was trying to run different cURL requests.  curl_multi_exec() ended up working great for me.